# How can I enter the IP address of our private VPN server in the Facebook development settings for our app?

Tags: facebook, web-deployment, facebook-oauth

We are building a asp .NET MVC web application for a school project. We have to deploy this website on a VPN server, which our school provided. We have succesfully deployed our project but our external logins (facebook/google) aren't working anymore. I figured out it was because of the fact that the website url of our project was still set to our localhost address. But when I try to change this URL into the IP of our VPN server we get the following error: "url is invalid because it is a Facebook url". Does anyone know why this happens and how I can resolve this? I'm extremely new to this so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the IP of your VPN?

Comment: @CBroe 10.134.216.25, provided by our school and only accessible within the network of school. I really have 0 experience with this kind of stuff. Is it even possible to get it to work?

Comment: You can't. Specify a domain instead and have your network point that domain to that IP

Comment: See, that’s an IP in the [private network range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) (and that’s why Facebook says “it is a Facebook url” – because from _their_ internal network, it is one of “their” IPs). Do as @WizKid says.